# PHP Recorrer valores de un Objeto, response __soapCall

Tags: php, soap, wsdl

Tengo una duda, estoy realizando pruebas consumiendo un `WebService` de tipo `SOAP WSDL`, al llamar un método que no requiere parámetros, me regresa como respuesta un listado de muchos productos, pero el problema es que regresa todos los productos en una sola cadena de texto, osea no muestra los datos de cada producto en un `arra`y.

Este es mi código en `PHP`:

```
$wsdl = "http://servidor-test.com/Servicio.asmx?wsdl";

$client = new SoapClient($wsdl);

$result = $client->__soapCall("Catalogo",array());

pr($result);
```

Y esto es lo que muestra al imprimir la variable $result

```
stdClass Object
  (
     [CatalogoResult] => stdClass Object
       (
         [any] => 013059 NM-200,NA,Antimonio,ST NM-200, Material:NA, 
                  Color:Antimonio, Talla:ST 1200 NM-200
       )
  )
```

En esta respuesta están revueltos los valores de varios campos, osea no están separados, por ejemplo, debería estar así:

```
[ProductoId] => 013059,
[Descripcion] => NM-200,NA,Antimonio,ST,
[Desc_Deta] => NM-200, Material:NA, Color:Antimonio, Talla:ST
```

¿Hay alguna forma de convertir así en `array` la información de cada producto?

Espero y puedan orientarme por favor.   Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que la respuesta del `SOAP` es una cadena `XML` y debes analizarla para poder acceder a los datos.

### Solución:

Para analizar el `XML` una opción es usar [`SimpleXMLElement`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/book.simplexml.php)

```
<?php

$wsdl = "http://irusalserver.dns-dns.com/eComerce/Servicio.asmx?wsdl";

$client = new SoapClient($wsdl);
$result = $client->Catalogo();
$xml = $result->CatalogoResult->any;

// Eliminamos los prefijos
$xml = str_replace(['diffgr:'], '', $xml);
// Metemos la respuesta en un elemento raiz (XML Standard)
$xml = "<document>" . $xml . "</document>";
// Cargamos el XML
$doc = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
// Accedemos al listado de items
$items = $doc->diffgram->CatalogoDT->children();

foreach ($items as $item) {
    // Imprimimos algunas propiedades de cada item `Catalogo`
    echo 'ProductId: ' . $item->Producto_id . ' - Desc: ' . $item->Descripcion . ' - Meta: '. $item->Desc_Deta.'<br>';
}
```

Comment: Hola @Marcos, muchas gracias por tu ayuda, funciona perfecto, Oye Marcos, en este mismo Servicio, hay un método llamado **GenerarVenta**, al cual debo enviar como parámetros 2 Objetos con 3 valores cada uno:

    **Encabezado**
       -FechaEntrega
       -Amex
       -Tarjeta

    **Cuerpo**
       -Producto_Id
       -Cantidad
       -Precio

Pero en la respuesta me sale este error: object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Intente probar el método con SoapUI, pero me da error, aveces me dice que la cantidad es null o que el atributo colum no puede ser nulo.

Comment: Hola @Marcos, mira yo lo hice con [este código] (https://pastebin.com/u8uDdMex) pero el error es: 

    El campo Cantidad de la columna Cuerpo es BDNull, he tratado de enviarlo como entero y decimal, pero me sigue dando el mismo error.

Comment: @JuanEscutiaGonzález, esta seguro del que el `WS` funciona? Usando [este código](https://pastebin.com/kpBrgY4D) me sale este error `Error:El argumento \'column\' no puede ser nulo. Nombre del parámetro: column`. Y si le quito a `Cantidad` y a `Producto_Id` el atributo `type="xx"` me da este otro error `Error:El valor de la columna \'Cantidad\' de la tabla \'Cuerpo\' es DBNull`. Se puede sacar `VentaDT` y el resultado va a ser el mismo.

Comment: gracias por toda tu ayuda, pues he intentado probarlo primero con SoapUI, pero ni ahí puedo hacer que funcione, como es la primer vez que trabajo con un webservice, primero quería comprobar que funciona, de lo contrario indicarle al desarrollador del webservice que algo anda mal, teniendo la certeza de que no es error mio.

Ya le he comentado al desarrolador el error que me sale y me dice que no hay ningún error, que según el ya lo probó y no tuvo ese error.

Comment: esta es la documentación que me dió:

El método para generación de ventas es **GenerarVenta**
Este recibe como parmetro un DataSet del tipo **VentaDT**, dentro del servicio esta publicada esta estructura

Tiene dentro 2 tablas, **Encabezado** y **Cuerpo**

Encabezado:
Lleva la Fecha de Entrega, el Monto pagado en American Express (Amex) y el Monto pagado con otra tarjeta (Tarjeta)

Cuerpo:
 Lleva un registro por cada producto vendido
 Producto_Id : es el código de producto
 Cantidad: es la cantidad Vendida
 Precio: Es el precio al que se vendio con Impuestos Incluidos

Comment: @JuanEscutiaGonzález, yo le pasaría el código que te deje en mi ultimo comentario y le pediría que me diga donde esta el error. [Este código](https://pastebin.com/kpBrgY4D) es un `POST` tal cual dice la [documentación de `GenerarVenta `](http://irusalserver.dns-dns.com/eComerce/Servicio.asmx?op=GenerarVenta)

Comment: muchas gracias por toda tu ayuda, le mandaré el código para ver su respuesta.